# Scaling 3D face model based on known distance between eyes

Tags: modeling, scale, measurement

I am trying to scale my 3D face model I build with KeenTools.
I was told that if I know the real measurement between, for example, the eyes of the model, I can scale the entire 3D face model based on that measurement.

Does anyone know the specific menu I have to go to, to select the measurement between the eyes, but then change it, so everything is scaled?

Comment: Hello :). I don't think it's a native Blender functionality. You can do this easily using a second object - snap its edges to the measured part, then enter the real dimensions, and then copy the scale values.

Comment: Thank you for answering haha! I guess it makes sense why I couldn't find this function. Going to follow your recommendation. Cheers! :))

Comment: No problem :). You can make it even easier by first parenting the head to the "other object". Then you don't have to copy the scale.